# Filling HTML Table with Dropwdownlists Change event in MVC

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax

I was trying to implement change event equivalent in MVC dropdownlist where it will fill the table below with relavant data from database.

But my Ajax call is not hitting the controller action method. can anybody tell me where I am  mistaken

View and vavascript

```
@model WebArtSampler.Models.AssignRequestModel


@{
    ViewBag.Title = "AssignRequest";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}


<h2>AssignRequest</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm("AssignRequestNew", "SamCutAssignmentMasters"))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">

        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.CutAssignID)

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CutAssignID, "Cutting Request #", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">


                @*@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CutAssignID, (SelectList)ViewBag.CutAssignID, "--Select One--", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })*@

                @Html.DropDownList("Id", (SelectList)ViewBag.CutAssignID, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })


            </div>
        </div>

}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
<div id="div1">

    <table class="table">
        <tr>
            <th>
                Req#
            </th>
            <th>
                Buyer
            </th>
            <th>
                Pattern Ref#
            </th>


            <th>
                Style
            </th>
            <th>
                Style Description
            </th>
            <th>
                Fabric
            </th>



           </tr>

        @foreach (var student in Model.Reqnumlist)
        {

            <tr>
                <td>
                    @student.ReqNum
                </td>
                <td>
                    @student.BuyerName
                </td>
                <td>
                    @student.PatterRefNum
                </td>
                <td>
                    @student.StyleName
                </td>
                <td>
                    @student.StyleDescription
                </td>

                <td>
                    @student.Fabric
                </td>

            </tr>

        }



    </table>

</div>
```

JQuery I used is

```
  <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function () {

            debugger;
            $("#Id").change(function () {

                debugger
                var Id = $(this).find('option:selected').val();            
                $.ajax({
                    url: "@Url.Action("PopulateDetails","SamCutAssignmentMasters")",
                    type: 'Get',
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: 'json',
                    data: { 'Id': Id },
                    success: function (data) {
                        if (data.success) {

                            debugger
                            document.getElementById("ProductName").value = data.productName;
                        }
                        else {
                            alert('invalid ID' + data.success);
                        }
                    }
                });




            });


        });

    </script>
```

Model

```
 public class SamCutAssignmentMastersController : Controller
    {
    [HttpGet]
        public JsonResult PopulateDetails(int id)
        {

            return Json(GetDetailsofaspecificTicket(id));
        }

   }
```

Comment: Are you sure the id of the drop down list is id? If I want it to be different from the model name, I usually have to set it in the html attributes, eg: `{ @class = "form-control", id = "Id" }`

Comment: Does `debugger`  within change event gets hit on dropdown change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, check the specification for UrlHelper.Action, you're trying to use this overload:

```
public virtual string Action(
    string actionName,
    string controllerName
)
```

You have the action and controller names the wrong way round. In circumstances like this it's usually worth doing a "View source" on your code, you could have then seen that the url was incorrect.

Also you will need to update the syntax of your ajax call where you are passing the id parameter to:

```
data: { 'Id': Id },
```

Comment: Thanks bro ,Updated it but still seems to have some issue

Comment: In your ajax call try: data: { id = Id }

Comment: Have you tried tracing the call in Fiddler or a similar tool?

Comment: Yes now when I made the Id value Action=0 its hitting the action means my Id value is not being passed to Action

Comment: as Pete has commented, are you sure your dropdown list actually has an Id of "Id"?

Comment: data: { 'Id': Id }, Solved the issue... can u update the answer so that I can mark it as completed